# Why use "ModelBindingContext" over "ControllerContext" in a custom model binder?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, modelbinders

Trying to phrase this as a question because in a problem I'm currently working on I'm unsure what benefits using the ModelBindingContext gives me over the ControllerContext.  Every example seems to say that using ModelBindingContext to get values is better, but not really clear why (and in my situation almost seems like it won't do what I want).

*Note: this example is simplified for this explanation to illustrate the major issue I'm having with the two, there's a lot more in the full scenario which means the default model binder is an option.*

At it's most basic we have the following (subset of) FORM data being posted across:

```
id=Question12 value='x'
id=Question45 value='y'
id=Question999 value='z'
```

If I was to get to the Request Object inside "ControllerContext" I could get to FORM.Keys to get all the data keys that were posted and I would know there were 3 and their id's (and could get their values).  It would be really easy.  There could be 0 or 1+ questions being posted per page (*the question type is important as to why the default model binder won't work for us, but is important in this issue*).

If I use "ValueProvider" on "ModelBindingContext" I can call "ContainsPrefix" or "GetValue", that's it.  So I could find out if it has values of "Question*" - but to find the 3 values posted it would appear that I would have to go through checking for "Question1" thru "Question999" just to find the 3 values and I still wouldn't know if I had them all!

As I say a lot of examples I've read say you should consider using ModelBindingContext, but it seems to be limited on functionality so just wondering if we'd be coding ourselves into a hole if we used ControllerContext instead?